Problem with FTP server regarding data upload via Webin-CLI
I'd like to upload my data (only two sequences) into my project using Webin-CLI. I don't know why i so complicated process...
I read deeply into tutorial and what I did?

I created account and study (Project).
I downloaded latest release of Webin-CLI.
I downloaded and filled spreadsheet template for annotated sequences (https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/submit/webin).
I prepared the command for the files validation:

java -jar webin-cli-8.0.0.jar  -username my.email@my.email -password ********* -context sequence -manifest manifest.txt -validate
The validation was succesfull. So I decided to submit data:
java -jar webin-cli-8.0.0.jar  -username my.email@my.email -password ********* -context sequence -manifest manifest.txt -submit
And I recieved this error:
INFO : Your application version is 8.0.0
INFO : Please upgrade to Webin-CLI version 7.0.1 or later if you see the following error: Failed to initialise validator. Could not retrieve BioSample.
INFO : Connecting to FTP server : webin2.ebi.ac.uk
INFO : Creating report file: /my/path/./webin-cli.report
WARN : Retrying connecting to FTP server.
WARN : Retrying connecting to FTP server.
WARN : Retrying connecting to FTP server.
WARN : Retrying connecting to FTP server.
WARN : Retrying connecting to FTP server.
WARN : Retrying connecting to FTP server.
ERROR: Failed to connect to FTP server. Failed to upload files to server because of a system error.
ERROR: Some or all submissions failed. Please see application logs.

I read that it's good idea to use Aspera. So I installed it and I added -ascp to the command line and this is the result:
java -jar webin-cli-8.0.0.jar -ascp -username my.email@my.email -password ********* -context sequence -manifest manifest.txt -submit
INFO : Your application version is 8.0.0
INFO : Please upgrade to Webin-CLI version 7.0.1 or later if you see the following error: Failed to initialise validator. Could not retrieve BioSample.
INFO : Uploading files to : webin.ebi.ac.uk
INFO : Creating report file: /my/path/./webin-cli.report
WARN : Aspera upload failed. Client exit code : 1
WARN : Client error : 

I checked the connection with default Aspera server (ping) amd it worked. I do not have any firewall. I'm struggling with this problem for long time. Of course I wrote to ENA support however I haven't recieved the answer so far... Maybe you know how to fix it?
Session Stop  (Error: Client unable to connect to server (check UDP port and firewall))

WARN : Retrying file upload.
WARN : Aspera upload failed. Client exit code : 1
WARN : Client error :

